# Equality for rigidified line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, vector-bundles

Let $L$ and $M$ be two rigidified line bundles (see below for the definition) over a scheme $X\to S$, and assume we know that $ L \cong M\otimes F $ for some line bundle $F$.

### $$\text{Is it true that}\quad L = M \quad ? $$

I think so, since rigidified line bundles have no nontrivial automorphisms. Hence the isomorphism $ L \cong M\otimes F $ needs to be an identity, otherwise $L\to M\otimes F \to L$ would be a nontrivial automorphism of $L$. Thus we have $ L = M\otimes F $, and this in turn implies that $F=\mathcal{O}_X$ and therefore $L=M$.

Do you agree with my argument?

$$$$

Here's the definition for "rigidified" that I'm using:

> **Def:** A line bundle $L$ over $X\to S$ is rigidified over a section $\varepsilon : S\to X$ if we have $ \varepsilon^*L \cong \mathcal{O}_S $

In the above I assume a section is given, and the line bundle are rigidified over the same section.

Comment: What definition do you have for a rigidified line bundle?

Comment: @DoriBejleri: I edited the question to include the definition I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is true. In fact if we denote a rigidified line bundle as $(L,\sigma)$ where we make explicit the isomorphism $\sigma:\varepsilon^*L \to \mathcal{O}_S$, then the set of rigidified line bundles forms a group under

$$
(L,\sigma_L) \otimes (M, \sigma_M) = (L\otimes M, \sigma_L \otimes \sigma_M).
$$

We can verify $\sigma_L \otimes \sigma_M$ is the composition

$$
\varepsilon^*(L \otimes M) \cong \varepsilon^*L \otimes \varepsilon^*M \cong \mathcal{O}_S \otimes \mathcal{O}_S \cong \mathcal{O}_S.
$$

In particular, your equality holds true if and only if $F$ is trivial but this doesn't have to be true. For a reference see http://math.berkeley.edu/~molsson/Hangzhou-workshop-notes.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dori. I'm confused... why do you think $F$ is not trivial? Isn't correct to say that $L=M\otimes F$ implies $F$ trivial?

Comment: Because this is a group operation so we can take inverses to obtain nontrivial tensor product equalities. For example, take a nontrivial rigidified line bundle $L$, then it's inverse $L^\vee$ is rigidified and $L \otimes L^\vee = \mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: Oh sure! I now realize that my "argument" was complete nonsense... thanks!